# Android Studio - Add subfolder without new package

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a package `com.myapp.api` which includes a couple of helper classes and lots of model classes. For the sake of organization, I wish I could place all the models in a subfolder called `Models`.

When I do that, Android Studio will mark an error on every model file, saying that their packages should be named `com.myapp.api.Models` instead.

Renaming the package wouldn't be a big deal, but I need those models to access some package-visible methods and variable present in the helper classes. If I rename, I must make those methods and variables public, and I don't want to.

Is there any way to force Android Studio not to try to create a new package based on the files structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is no. This isn't an Android Studio thing, it's a Java thing -- directories on disk correspond to packages.

If you're really motivated to work around it, you could set up multiple source folders, e.g.

- **src/main/java/com/myapp/api**
- **src/main/java-models/com/myapp/api**

and manipulate `srcDirs` in your **build.gradle** to add the new source directories:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java-models']
}
```

but that's kind of a confusing way to organize your source, and it's a pattern you rarely see.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think that this is possible. I'm pretty sure that this is mandated by the Java Language Specification, although I couldn't tell you which section exactly.